# Understanding Logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I’m currently in my senior year of high school and we just started on the topic of logs, when doing textbook work I encountered a problem and I am confused on where I’m going wrong. Could any body help?

$$2^x+1 = 3^x-1 \implies x\log2 + \log2 = x\log3 - \log3$$
After this I don’t know where to go.

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE. Please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/570189) to improve readability and increase your chances to get meaningful answers.

Comment: After that is just a linear equation. You should be able to find $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, the values $\log 2$ and $\log 3$ are just real numbers, so you're now trying to solve the equation $ax + a = bx - b$, where $a=\log 2$ and $b = \log 3$.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$x(\ln(2)-\ln(3))=-\ln(2)-\ln(3)$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$\ldots \iff x\log3-x\log2 =\log3+\log2 $$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the log of the LHS and RHS is
\begin{align*}
\log(2^{x + 1}) &= \log(3^{x-1})\\
(x+1)\cdot\log(2) &= (x-1)\cdot\log(3)\\
x\log(2) + \log(2) &= x\log(3) - \log(3)\\
\Rightarrow x &= -\frac{\log(3) + \log(2)}{\log(2) - \log(3)} \approx 42.78468556
\end{align*}